# How to fix TextInputLayout passwordToggle?

Tags: java, android, android-textinputlayout, android-support-design, android-textinputedittext

I created a simple login page with validations but i have a problem in the password section when i want to use **passwordToggleEnabled** the app crash and don't open no idea why since i have 0 errors.

My project in on API 26.

I have added in build gradle inside dependicies:

```
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
```

And inside the XML file this is my code of password input:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/test2"
            android:layout_below="@id/usernameEditText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            app:errorEnabled="true"
            app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Your Password"
                android:inputType="textPassword" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

and in MainActivity.java this is how i am calling the id of pwd:

```
String passwordInput = test2.getText().toString().trim();
```

So this is how am implementing my code and the app keeps stopping so what i am doing wrong ?

Thank you!

Comment: What does it mean *My project in on API 26* ? Also post the logcat of your crash

Comment: Sorry i am new to android studio i didn't know that i can see my errors in logcat.

Comment: Debug your app and use the Logcat panel in the bottom of the screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the method [`getEditText`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TextInputLayout) to get the `EditText` used for text input:

```
TextInputLayout test2= findViewById(R.id.test2);
String passwordInput = test2.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();
```

Comment: Thank you ! My mistake was i didn't assign an id for the EditText now its solved but got a simple problem is the toggle and the error message appear very close to each other how can i fix this ? https://i.imgur.com/zGlDJ2h.png  @Gabriele Mariotti

Comment: @SmithBZ This is a separate problem. It has nothing to do with your question. You may wish to consider asking a separate question with the code used and a screen to help the community. Also consider to migrate the design library to the [material components library](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android).

Comment: Yes you're right.Anyway thank you for your help much appreciated @Gabriele Mariotti

Answer (score 1):

You have to first find the view by assigning it an ID like this

```
  <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/etPassword"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Your Password"
                    android:inputType="textPassword" />
```

and then find it in your activity like this

```
 TextInputEditText etPassword= findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
```

then you can get the entered text like

```
String passwordInput = etPassword.getText().toString().trim();
```

Answer (score 0):

Assigning an ID to TextInputEditText

```
  <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/etPassword"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Your Password"
                    android:inputType="textPassword" />
```

and then find it in your activity like this

```
EditText etPassword= findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
```

then you can get the entered text like

```
String mPassword = etPassword.getText().toString().trim();
```

Comment: And what is the difference with the @Somesh answer?

Comment: lol, almost the same, I didn't check his answer, Go with anyone of it!